# Powershell Jagged/Multidimensional Array initialization

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to read a set of data and place it in an array "cell by cell".
in my head the array should look like this:

```
[0,0][0,1][0,2]
[1,0][1,1][1,2]
[2,0][2,1][2,2]
[3,0][3,1][3,2]
[4,0][4,1][4,2]
```

I'm pretty sure its a Jagged array I am after, I want to be able to assign a value to each cell individually, in my testing I can assign values row by row no problem. but that doesn't help me.

My basic code looks like this:

```
$Array = @()
for ($row=0; $row=4; $row++){
    for ($column=0; $column=2; $column++){
        $Array[$row][$column] += @("Row: $row, Column: $column")


    }
}
```

It should just go through cell by cell putting some information in each cell

I've had a look through the usual suspects which are referenced on Powershell Array questions here;

- www.leedesmond.com/weblog/?p=183
- 4sysops.com/archives/arrays-in-powershell-create-change-read-sort-delete/
- en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell/Arrays_and_Hash_Tables#Adding_Elements_to_an_Array

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Even if i use the examples in that  and modify my code to

```
$Array = New-Object 'object[,]' 3,3
```

my output is just a list:

```
Row: 0, Column: 0
Row: 0, Column: 1
Row: 1, Column: 0
Row: 1, Column: 1
```

I was expecting a table layout

Comment: See specifically the answer CB. provided to the other question. In your case you have a 3*5*2 element array.

Comment: Edit: moved it to question

Comment: Is this question about initilizing a multidimensional array, or about displaying its elements?